# json_decode($data) PHP

Tags: php, json

Estou usando o `json_decode` em cima de um arquivo GeoJSON. Tudo que preciso é imprimir na tela uma *feature* específica do arquivo, que a saber tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
var GEOJSON = {

"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "02", "NOME": "xxxxxxxxx", "TIPO": "xxxxxx", " }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -90.00012544789, -47.012254699888 ] } }, (...)
```

Possuo vários pontos com a estrutura mostrada, mas como faço para imprimir na tela um valor especifico?

Tentei:

```
echo $tr->features[0]->properties->ID;
```

Mas não conseguí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) passando o segundo parâmetro como `true` para que tudo seja convertido para `array` associativo.

```
$geojson = '{"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": {"type": "name","properties": {"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {"ID": "02","NOME": "xxxxxxxxx","TIPO": "xxxxxx"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [ -90.00012544789, -47.012254699888 ]}}]}';
$geojson_array = json_decode($geojson, true);

echo $geojson_array['features'][0]['properties']['ID'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Oi! Talvez o modo como eu fiz abaixo possa te ajudar.

```
$geojson = '{"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": {"type": "name","properties": {"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {"ID": "02","NOME": "xxxxxxxxx","TIPO": "xxxxxx"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [ -90.00012544789, -47.012254699888 ]}}]}';
$geojson_array = json_decode($geojson);
$geojson_array = (array)$geojson_array;

echo $geojson_array["features"][0]->properties->ID;

die;
```

Abraço.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado shoogie!! Resolveu 100%, eu já estava há dias com essa questão!

Comment: De nada, que bom que deu certo!!! :D